# How to use isolated scope action with parameter from one directive to another

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive I want to pass isolated scoped action with parameter from one directive to another. please see the Plunker.

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KAjb8x7GQ4SYRvz95tVH?p=preview)

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.singleClick = function (test) {
    alert('singleClick'+test);
  }
});

app.directive('myButton', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="button" value="Click" ng-click="click("test")" />',
    scope: { onSingleclick: '&singleclickFn' },
     link: function (scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            scope.click = function (test) {
                alert('singleClick'+test);
                scope.onSingleclick(test); 
            }
        }
  };
}]);

app.directive('myNewButton', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { singleclick: '&singleclickFn' },
    template: '<my-button singleclick-fn="singleclick(test)" />',
  };
}]);
```

In controller method I have got parameter is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from directive with isolated scope to the parent scope pass an object as argument instead of the primitive. So in your **myButton** directive use something like

```
ng-click="click({inp:'test'})
```

and access the argument as object in the singleClick function of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

In your plunkr i can see you pass the result of the function execution to you directive instead of the function itself. Therefore it is undefined as the function doesn't return anything.

use `singleclick-fn="singleClick"` to pass the funciton to your directive's scope.

Please make your plunkr work (I get errors in the console if i open it), so i can verify the error

Comment: Please see I need to pass parameter. So I have set parameter in my method. Please help me to remove inconsistency.